# Strange sounds from sky.

Tags: video

http://www.dailymail.co.uk/travel/travel_news/article-3084260/What-strange-sound-sky-Noise-heard-globe-nearly-DECADE-explanation.html

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=4JHAu5qDSgU

What is it? The Internet is full of stories with them being alien spaceship zooming by.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) This is not a site for inviting people's opinions and speculations. If there is a particular claim about the sounds, we may be able to address whether it is true. (We already have questions about the existence of alien spaceships. It's clear anyone reaching the conclusion that it must be a spaceship is speculating pretty wildly.)

Comment: Answered: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/27758/is-there-any-scientific-explanation-for-this-trumpet-noise-from-the-atmosphere